# Intellij IDEA automatically resolving all maven dependencies

Tags: maven, svn, intellij-idea, import

Since I'm working with a HUGE project, I would like to add maven modules one by one when I'll be in need to.

Unfortunately, Intellij IDEA is resolving all maven dependencies right after project import. Is there any way to stop this, or shutdown automatic resolve right after import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij Idea has an option in the Maven preferences for controlling this.

```
Preferences
    Build, Execution, Deployment
        Build Tools
            Maven
                Importing
```

Uncheck the box for "Import Maven projects automatically"